# Can't fill array with firestore data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a Firestore web app. I configured my database etc... And everything is right.
But I'm now trying to get data from the firebase, store it in a variable (or fill array with those data) and do my computation on this variable that I will update every 30 sec (I do this to limit the number of query).

I can access to the data and read them without any problem but I can't add them. I've tried to put the variable in global, pass it through the function as argument but nothing works.

Here is my code:

```
userArray = [];

db.collection("scenario-name").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          userArray.push(doc.id);
      });
});


console.log(userArray);
```

But I got something like this :

https://ibb.co/j3YdfLj

I also tried the .push.apply, or to define a function and pass userArray in it or even to do this kind of stuff :

```
userArray = [];

db.collection("scenario-name").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          apply(doc);
      });
});

function apply(doc){
    userArray.push(doc.id);
}
```

Can I store a firestore query querying the whole document and work on it? Or should I do a query for every stuff? How can I store in a variable?

Thank you!

Comment: `get()` is asynchronous and returns immediately, before the query is complete.  Your code goes on an executes without waiting for it, which means `userArray` is initially empty.  Some time later, the promise returned by `get()` becomes resolved, and your callback is invoked.  You should wait to use the results of the query until this callback happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears pasted directly from Firestore documentation, so I would imagine that the issue is with the structure of the data, or the data, as it is stored in Firestore.

[Get all documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection)

```
db.collection("cities").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

You are doing it right, creating an empty array variable then iterating your `querySnapshot`, pushing the ID of the document on each iteration. Validate what you are getting from the `.get()` using `console.log`. You should be good to go.

Comment: I think Doug is right in the comments of my initial post. I think this is cause it's asynchronous.